# Xephyr not running on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: xorg, 19.10

I am on Ubuntu 19.10 and I am facing certain problems with Xephyr. I have installed Xephyr by:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xephyr
```

And I am trying to start Xephyr by:

```
Xephyr -br -ac -noreset -screen 800x600 :1
```

But when I do so I get the following errors:

```
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)
```

Pls help me. Something feels strange here. As far as I know Xephyr is supposed to be a nested X Session, so why is it asking to make sure 'an X server isn't already running'.

Comment: It seems that an X server is already running on :1. You should change it to :2 or a suitable different value

Comment: @RayWu Thanks, that seeemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that an X server is already running on :1. You should change it to :2 or a suitable different value.

ex: `Xephyr -br -ac -noreset -screen 800x600 :2`